# How to login user with Laravel and Passport

Tags: php, laravel

I have to do a job for a course. I have to try to make a Rest API for Laravel. For that, I installed Passport.

I followed several tutorials on the internet and realized a login function in my Auth / LoginController

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('auth')->accessToken;
        $success['user'] = $user;
        return response()->json($success, 201);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

I test with Postman and everything seems to work. As well as my logout function

```
public function logout()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->token()->revoke();
    $user->token()->delete();

    return response()->json(null, 204);
}
```

Now, I try to integrate that into my front end.

I can connect with Laravel's basic login form. Only he redirects me to the json of my login () function.

When I refresh the page, it redirects me to the dashboard (it is that I am well connected). In my database, the token is well created.

How to use the basic Laravel auth to use Passport or did I not understand something?

Answer (score 0):

```
// When you make login request, basically u r making a post request, 
// But when u refresh the page, get request is made

So, to go to dashboard page on login success, you must redirect to dashboard page
on login attempt success, e.g

enter code here// use Auth attempt to login with the provided credentials

// if get success redirect to the dashboard
public function login(Request $request) {
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $success['token'] = $user->createToken('auth')->accessToken;
        $success['user'] = $user;

        // return response()->json($success, 201);
        return redirect('/dashboard'); // your dashboard path
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}

Hope it works...
```

Answer (score 0):

After install [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/passport).
You can follow this code --

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
            'remember_me' => 'boolean'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);
        $user = $request->user();

        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;

        if ($request->remember_me)
            $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addDays(5);
        $token->save();

        return response()->json([
            'token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
            'user' => auth()->user(),
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
                $tokenResult->token->expires_at
            )->toDateTimeString()
        ]);
    }
```

For logout you have to set logout routes in api routes --

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
        Route::post('logout','UserController@logout');
});
```

Then use logout function in your auth controller

```
     /**
     * Logout user (Revoke the token)
     *
     * @return [string] message
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->user()->tokens->each(function ($token, $key) {
            $token->delete();
        });

        return response()->json('Logged out successfully', 200);
    }
```